# Farthest points in convex hull

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, emgucv

I am working on a hand recognition project. At this point I'm able to detect the hand and I found the contour of the hand and convex hull points using the following code:

```
Contour<Point> contours = imageThreshold.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,
   Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST, storage);
   Contour<Point> largestcontour = contours;
   while (contours != null)
   {
      if(largestcontour.Area < contours.Area)
      {
         largestcontour = contours;
      }

      contours = contours.HNext;
   }
   if (largestcontour != null)
   {
      Seq<Point> convexHull = largestcontour.GetConvexHull(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ORIENTATION.CV_CLOCKWISE);
      foreach (var hullPoint in convexHull)
      {
         CvInvoke.cvCircle(ColorFrame, hullPoint, 3, new MCvScalar(255), 2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, 0);
      }

      CvInvoke.cvDrawContours(ColorFrame, convexHull, new MCvScalar(255),
                        new MCvScalar(128), 1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, new Point(0, 0));

   }
```

In the output there is more than one point on each fingertip. What I want is to get one point on each fingertip.

After doing some research, what I understood is that to get one point on each fingertip I need to find the farthest point from each vertex in the convex hull.

How do I get farthest points in convex hull?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at:
http://geomalgorithms.com/a14-_extreme_pts.html

It contains explanations and code-examples that might help you out.

Comment: If you have an answer that you would like to add to this link use the answer section. In order to only provide links please use the comments section. You might end up getting a negative score for this!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [convexity defects](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gada4437098113fd8683c932e0567f47ba). I suppose it is what you need. For example, it should help you find more accurate center of hand, directions of fingers and other stuff.